# How do I filter null values from a query?

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to filter the null values from the following query and it keeps giving me 2 records instead of 1.

Here is my base query
[image: Source]

The following query brings me back 2 results and I only need to see one result as there is only one vender for vendor_id 91.  it's giving me a record for the null and an 'N' for the result of my case statement.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN vs.User_Data_Field1 = '14' THEN 'Y'
            WHEN vs.User_Data_Field2 = '14' THEN 'Y'
            WHEN vs.User_Data_Field3 = '14' THEN 'Y'
            WHEN vs.User_Data_Field4 = '14' THEN 'Y' 
            WHEN vs.User_Data_Field5 = '14' THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
       END USER_DATA_FIELD
FROM RHOP..EDSLKP.VENDOR_SITES VS
where vendor_id = '91' 
GROUP BY VENDOR_ID,VS.USER_DATA_FIELD1,VS.USER_DATA_FIELD2,VS.USER_DATA_FIELD3,VS.USER_DATA_FIELD4,VS.USER_DATA_FIELD5
ORDER BY VENDOR_ID
```

[image]

My question is, How do I code this to only bring back one 'N' for the one vendor?

Thanks for any help

Comment: It's showing multiple rows because you are grouping by all those fields, some of which are different. What's your intended logic here: do you want to show `Y` if *any* `User_Data_Field` on *any* row with that `VENDOR_ID` is 14, and `N` otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly (that you want to return `Y` if *any* `User_Data_Field` for *any* matching row is 14), you can do something like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(IIF(User_Data_Field1 = 14, 1, 0)
                    +IIF(User_Data_Field2 = 14, 1, 0)
                    +IIF(User_Data_Field3 = 14, 1, 0)
                    +IIF(User_Data_Field4 = 14, 1, 0)
                    +IIF(User_Data_Field5 = 14, 1, 0)) > 0 THEN 'Y'
ELSE 'N'
END USER_DATA_FIELD
FROM RHOP..EDSLKP.VENDOR_SITES VS
WHERE vendor_id = '91' 
GROUP BY VENDOR_ID
ORDER BY VENDOR_ID
```

`IIF` is only supported in SQL 2012 and above, so prior to that you'll have to stick with `CASE WHEN`.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly, you want 1 row per vendor_id, with 2 columns:

1. vendor_id
2. yesno ('Y' if any user data field is 14, 'N' otherwise)

since you restrict on vendor_id=91, you expect 1 result row.

as bradc already mentioned, your group-by clause is wrong. you should group by vendor_id only.
try this:

```
select vendor_id, max(yesno)
from
  (select vendor_id
  , (case when user_data_field1='14' 
            or user_data_field2='14' 
            or user_data_field3='14' 
            or user_data_field4='14' 
            or user_data_field5='14' 
          then 'Y' 
          else 'N'
    end)  as yesno  
 from vs) a
 where vendor_id = 91
 group by vendor_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a solution for multiple vendors
UNION enforces distinct

```
with cte as 
( select vendorID 
  from FROM RHOP..EDSLKP.VENDOR_SITES 
  where User_Data_Field1 = '14'
     or User_Data_Field2 = '14' 
     or User_Data_Field3 = '14' 
     or User_Data_Field4 = '14' 
     or User_Data_Field5 = '14' 
)
select vendorID, 'Y' as 'USER_DATA_FIELD' 
from cte
union 
select vendorID, 'N' 
from RHOP..EDSLKP.VENDOR_SITES vs 
where not exists ( select 1 
                   from cte 
                   where cte.vendorID = vs.vendorID 
                 )
```